# "En tout cas" vs "quoi qu'il en soit"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

J'aimerais savoir si on peut utiliser *en tout cas* et *quoi qu'il en soit* de manière interchangeable par exemple dans les phrases suivantes:

> Ce n’était pas ce qu’il attendait de la vie il y a quelques mois... **En tout cas/quoi qu'il en soit**, il est convaincu qu’il se sent si bien aujourd'hui parce qu'il a enfin trouvé un travail qui lui plait.

> Je pense que t’exagères un peu! Mais **en tout cas/quoi qu'il en soit**, merci pour ces mots gentils!

> Paul joue du piano depuis dix ans et il est plutôt fort. Mais malgré ça, il joue seulement quand il est tout seul. Il préfère pas être au centre de l’attention. **En tout cas/quoi qu'il en soit**, malheureusement Paul ne peut pas toujours jouer du piano, il doit aussi travailler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les sens des deux expressions sont proches, mais *quoi qu'il en soit* est d'un registre plus soutenu. Il n'est pas très compatible avec le reste de certaines de tes phrases qui utilisent une langue relâchée, parlée (*t'exagères*, *il préfère pas*).

Dans la première phrase, les deux me semblent utilisables sans différence notable. Je modifierais la fin comme ça:

> en tout cas, il est convaincu **que s’il** se sent si bien aujourd'hui, **c'est** parce qu'il a enfin trouvé un travail qui lui plait.

Dans la deuxième phrase, je choisirais *en tout cas*.

Dans la troisième phrase, il faudrait choisir entre *malheureusement* et *en tout cas*. Les deux s'accordent mal. Ou alors, déplacer *malheureusement* à la fin : *il doit malheureusement aussi travailler*.

Answer (score 0):

> ([Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/quoi-qu-il-en-soit/)) **quoi qu'il en soit**, locution
> Sens :    En tout état de cause, de toute façon.

> ([La culture générale](https://www.laculturegenerale.com/quoi-quil-en-soit-ou-quoiquil-en-soit-orthographe/))  On écrit : quoi qu'il en soit. Cette locution adverbiale est invariable. Elle signifie « de toute façon », « en tout cas », « en tout état de cause ».

Comment: Ton dernier paragraphe est hors sujet et incompréhensible pour qui n'a pas suivi le lien. Il est de plus inexact : *Quoiqu'il en soit probablement capable, il refuse d'admettre ses erreurs.*

Comment: @jlliagre Ça n'est pas la locution « quoi qu'il en soit » puisque « soit » a comme attribut « probablement capable » (pas d'attribut dans la locution qui est discutée) ; le paragraphe n'est pas hors sujet, puisque je dois corriger une partie de la référence, celle-ci étant inexacte en ce qui concerne l'orthographe.

Comment: Quelle référence est inexacte ? Quel rapport avec la question posée ?

Comment: @jlliagre La référence du site « La culture Générale » ; ils disent bien que la conjonction « quoique » peut-être le mot qui entre dans la constitution de cette conjonction, et je dis que cela n'est jamais correct. (J'aurais pu l'ignorer, mais on donne un lien et une vérification pourrait alors possiblement induire quelqu'un à conclure que cette orthographe convient.)

Comment: Ah bon ?? Tu es sûr d'avoir bien lu ?

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, j'ai bien lu, et ça vient d'être corrigé; je fais donc une rectification dans ma réponse.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est encore là: «Quoi qu'il en soit» ou «quoiqu'il en soit» | La culture générale https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=quoi+qu%27il+ensoit

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui a été corrigé ? Qu'est-ce qui était faux ?